# PostgreSQL get nested rows with limit

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query, sql-limit

I got a self referencing table that's only 1 deep: comments and replies. A reply is just a comment with a parent id:

```
Comments (simplified):
    - comment_id
    - parentCommentId
```

Users have to scroll through the comments and replies and typically 10 new rows are being fetched each time, I'm trying out an recursive query for this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE included_childs(comment_id, parent_comment_id) AS 
    (SELECT comment_id, parent_comment_id
    FROM comments 
  UNION 
    SELECT c.comment_id, c.parent_comment_id
    FROM included_childs ch, comments c
    WHERE c.comment_id = ch.parent_comment_id
  )
SELECT *
FROM included_childs
limit 10
```

obviously because of `limit 10` not all the childs are being included this way and conversations will be cut off. What I actually want is a limit on the parents and have all childs included, regardless of how many total rows.

**update**

This is the actual query, now with limit in the first branch:

```
WITH RECURSIVE included_childs(comment_id, from_user_id, fk_topic_id, comment_text, parent_comment_id, created) AS 
    ((SELECT comment_id, from_user_id, fk_topic_id, comment_text, parent_comment_id, created 
    FROM vw_comments WHERE fk_topic_id = 2
    and parent_comment_id is null
    limit 1)
  union all 
    SELECT c.comment_id, c.from_user_id, c.fk_topic_id, c.comment_text, c.parent_comment_id, c.created
    FROM included_childs ch, vw_comments c
    WHERE c.comment_id = ch.parent_comment_id
  )
SELECT *
FROM included_childs
```

still, this doesn't give me the expected results, I get 1 comment as a result with no replies.

**update 2**

silly mistake on the where clause:

```
WHERE c.comment_id = ch.parent_comment_id
```

should've been

```
WHERE ch.comment_id = c.parent_comment_id
```

it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first branch in the `UNION` in the recursive CTE should be something like:

```
SELECT comment_id, parent_comment_id
FROM comments
WHERE parent_comment_id IS NULL
LIMIT 10
```

Then you'd get all replies for these 10 "root" comments.
I'd expect some sort of `ORDER BY` in there, unless you don't care for the order.

`UNION ALL` would be fester than `UNION`, and there cannot be cycles, right?

Comment: When I limit in the first branch to 1 (with parentcommentid is null) I still get only 1 row? I simplified the query for the question, that's why I omitted the where clause. I'll update my answer.

Comment: If that comment has no responses, yes. But maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: nevermind, I see my mistake now (switched branch in the where clause, needed to be ch.comment_id = c.parent_comment_id)